# Intellij IDEA code coverage incorrectly shows less than 100%

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I have a package with five classes. Each class has 100% code coverage, 100% line coverage bar one (which has 98% line coverage). As a result the package code coverage is 88% and line coverage is 171%. It doesn't really make sense to me (especially the 171% line coverage) and I was wondering if anyone had encountered this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-65123?), try IDEA 11 EAP version.

Comment: Thanks. Will check out the pre-release version.